# Protractor and locating element

Tags: protractor

I need to locate elemet "username" using Protractor.
I have used

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
```

due to the fact that the login page is not Angular.

My script is as simple as this:

```
describe('slowchat', function() {
it('start test', function() {

     browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
     browser.get('https://www.test.no/eai/bankid20');

     element(by.css('[value="Logg inn"]')).click();

     browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);




});
});
```

However I get error:

```
  Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, [value="Logg inn"])
```

Please see attachment for the place I want to locate.

[image: inspect pic]

Any idea why this is not able to locate the button?

Comment: have you tried to debbug it with sleep ? Maybe it's just a problem, that element is not yet visible.

Comment: how do I spesify that in my attached script?

Comment: did not help. browser.sleep(35000)

Comment: try `element(by.css('form#loginform   input#submit')).click();`

Answer (score 0):

Now i saw that in circle is input with `username` but you ask about button to submit the form, btw you can turn off angular by flag

```
   //entering non-angular site
browser.ignoreSynchronization=true;
   //Some code
   element(by.css('button[onclick="mySubmit()"])).click();
   //when you go back to angular site
browser.ignoreSynchronization=false;
```

Answer (score 0):

So when you disable waiting for angular or ignore synchronization, this means that you will need to roll your own waiting for some sort of stability. There are two ways you can accomplish this: 1. Turn off the control flow and use async await. 2. Resolve your promises before moving to the next action.

### Resolving promises

I think you need to use the `done()` method call here because of the async calls. My general take away on resolving promises is ew... prefer using async / await and removing the control flow.

```
describe('slowchat', () => {
  it('start test', (done) => {

   browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
   browser.get('https://www.test.no/eai/bankid20').then(() => {
     return element(by.css('[value="Logg inn"]')).click().then() => {
       browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
       done();
     });
   });
  });
});
```

### Using async / await and removing the control flow

The control flow is being deprecated so this will get you ahead of the curve. I would suggest doing it this way. It will make your tests easier to debug.

```
describe('slowchat', () => {
  it('start test', async() => {
   await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
   await browser.get('https://www.test.no/eai/bankid20');
   await element(by.css('[value="Logg inn"]')).click();
   await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
  });
});
```

When launching this you will need to set the flag to turn off the control flow. In your config, you'll need to add this: `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false`

Comment: Also in reference to the other answer. `ignoreSynchronization` and `waitForAngularEnabled` do the same thing.

Comment: Answer also references that it  is 'easier to debug'. We'll discuss this in depth next week at ng-conf. If you are there say hi. If not, check out the live stream / recorded vids.

Comment: The only thing to note is, ignoreSynchronization is being deprecated and eventually will no longer be available. They are switching to waitForAngularEnabled as the main property.

Comment: Yup, it was deprecated a while ago but we are now removing ignoreSynchronization.